# How to debug events in GA(GTM)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

On every page I have:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XX-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'XX-XXXXXXXXX-X');

    gtag('config', 'XX-XXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

And I have, for instance, one event:

```
gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'XX-XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX'});
```

I need any callback or how I as a developer could know that data would be sent to GA server?

Accepting any help, thank u!

P.S. And yes, I googled and tried what I've found

- I've implemented as shown here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events#default_google_analytics_events
- I tried this method (unsuccessfully) https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-hits#implement_event_callback_functions
- I've tried this method (unsuccessfully)
  https://flauntdigital.com/blog/fix-google-analytics-events-tag-manager/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using google tag assistant as mentioned over here

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/validate-with-tag-assistant